# Software for solving quadratic Diophantine equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations, math-software

Is there a tool for solving systems of quadratic Diophantine equations?

I know that satisfiability of such equations is undecidable in general, but I still hope that in simple cases software could decide (in particular if a solution exists).

I tried the online Wolfram Alpha and indeed, "solve x^2+y^2=10 over the integers" finds a solution, but "solve x^2+y^2=25 over the integers" already fails.

Comment: my favorite is this site. it gives you everything, just the solutions, step by step solutions and even the theory behind it if you click on methods ( left hand side right above the date). https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM

Comment: Thanks, but does it work for more variables and more equations?

Comment: it works for general quadratic equations. a*x^2 + b*xy + c*y^2 + d*x + e*y + f = 0. you may want to try it for you case and see what you get. (keep in mind that your equation should be written as x^2+y^2-10) and the coefficients b,d,e must be entered as 0.

Answer (score 3):

Wolfram Alpha utilized Wolfram Mathematica for questions like that and it can certainly solve your question (once you learn the syntax).

You can try it using [Wolfram's Programming Lab](https://lab.open.wolframcloud.com/app/). The interface/notation is the same as Mathematica uses but it has some limitations (it is free compared to the price of Mathematica) as far as how long/many calculations you can do.

Follow the link them down the bottom click on Create a New Notebook>

Then type in the following Mathematica command:

```
Solve[{x^2+y^2==25,Element[x,Integers],Element[y,Integers]},{x,y}]
```

It will give you all 12 solutions.

Breaking down this command it is made up of several parts which will let you answer similar questions.

- Solve[] - takes too inputs - an equation or list of equations then a variable or list of variables to solve for. A list is created by putting things in curvy brackets { and }.
- Element[] - tells Mathematica that the first argument is of type given by the second argument. For your case Integers will be all you need but Mathematica can work on a variety of types.

So basically its solve three equations/conditions. Firstly $x^2+y^2==10$ (Note the double equal sign for comparing equality. A single equal side is for assigning a variable.) The second and third are the conditions we require, i.e. that $x$ and $y$ are integers. These are all encases in curvy brackets to make them a list of equations. Then there is the list (also in curvy brackets) of variable, i.e. $\{x,y\}$.

Mathematica and Wolfram's Programming Lab can do *lots* of mathematical calculations but learning the language/syntax can be a bit of a steep learning curve. The Programming Lab does have built in help in the top right corner so have fun.